# What is the difference between electric multipole and magnetic multipole transitions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin, spectroscopy

Are electric and magnetic multipole transitions are classified based on the nature of change in angular momentum of an electron during a transition between two states?

In electric multipole transitions, the electron changes its orbital angular momentum, leading to transitions between different electron shells or orbitals within the same shell.

In magnetic multipole transitions, the electron changes its spin angular momentum, resulting in transitions between different spin states.

Answer (score 2):

### Electric Multipole Transitions:

In electric multipole transitions, the change in angular momentum comes from the electron altering its orbital angular momentum. This typically leads to transitions between different electron shells or orbitals within the same shell. These transitions are associated with the emission or absorption of electromagnetic radiation, such as photons, and are governed by the selection rules that dictate which transitions are allowed based on quantum mechanical principles. For example, transitions between different energy levels in atoms or molecules often involve electric dipole transitions.

### Magnetic Multipole Transitions:

In magnetic multipole transitions, the electron changes its spin angular momentum. This results in transitions between different spin states of the electron. These transitions can also involve the emission or absorption of electromagnetic radiation, but they are generally weaker compared to electric multipole transitions. Magnetic dipole transitions are an example of this, where the change in spin angular momentum leads to changes in the magnetic properties of the system.

**THE MAIN DEFFERENCE IS:**

Electric Multipole Transitions involve changes in the electron's orbital angular momentum. This means that the electron shifts between different orbitals within the same shell or even jumps between different electron shells altogether. These transitions are what lead to the emission or absorption of electromagnetic radiation, like light.

On the other hand, Magnetic Multipole Transitions focus on changes in the electron's spin angular momentum. Instead of altering its position within an atom, the electron switches between different spin states. This kind of transition affects the magnetic properties of the system, and although it can also involve the emission or absorption of radiation, these transitions are generally weaker than their electric counterparts.